# How can I use a regex to determine if a unumber is divisible by 5?

Tags: regex

I am trying regex to find out whether a number is divisible by 10 or by 5. So basically, I am trying to see whether the number end in 0 or 5.

This is my regular expression
`^[1-9]*0?.0$`

I encounter issues when the input is 100.0 or 55.0

What should the regular expression be?

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: Why are you using regex to do maths?

Comment: Some people, when they see a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions". Now they have two problems.

Comment: Please, do not do this with a regex.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply do

```
bool isDivisibleBy5 = ! (number % 5);
```

?  (You didn't specify what language you are using, but that syntax should at least be comprehensible if you come from a C-ish background.)

Answer (score 1):

If you *must* do this with regexes for some reason, then the answer is:

```
/^\d*[05]\.0$/
```

1. Beginning of string
2. Any number of digits (including none)
3. A '0' or '5'
4. A '.' (note backslash escaping since . is a regex metacharacter)
5. A '0'
6. End of string

Answer (score 1):

If you know that you are passing integer strings in then there is no need to check any other digits, just whether the digit before the end or decimal point is 5 or 0. Also I'm allowing any amount of 0's after the decimal point, because that's still divisible by 5.

```
/[05](?:\.0+)?$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression

^([1-9]{1,9}[05]+)|5$